# how to refresh table body after ajax success

Tags: ajax

```
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"abc.php",
            data:dataString,
            success:function(response){ 

            //alert(response);
            // Here I want to write code to refresh table body          
            }
    });
```

Comment: can you add the response data which you are getting on success.

Comment: in my html table thier are give change status button after click button abc.php page update status but after ajax success i want to show update status

Comment: So you want to show the update status in table??

Comment: yes bro.without page refresh because i use pageination in table

Answer (score 7):

Try This one by replacing table id in success function

```
        success:function(response){ 

          $("#table_id").load(window.location + " #table_id");

        }

Space in important.
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be late to the party, but you can easily do this by a two step process.

1. remove/delete the rows (rows() then remove()).
2. re-draw the table again (draw()).

You can then insert the below code inside your success function right before you request a new ajax call.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
var rows = table
    .rows()
    .remove()
    .draw();
```

I would advise reading this datatable API https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().remove()

If you still encounter issues, let me know how I can help.